# Bulk Update One2Many odoo Just Change 1 data From API response

Tags: orm, odoo, one2many

i create API with Odoo for consume in web apps, my problem it's when i bulk update from web apps which has form like this

[image]

and From clint side i got response JSON like this

```
[{"product_char": "A", "quantity": "1", "price_unit": "100"},
{"product_char": "M", "quantity": "1", "price_unit": "100"}]
```

and in the odoo controller this is my function :

```
@http.route([
    '/api/update/petty_cash/<int:id>'
], type='http', auth="none", methods=['POST'], csrf=False)
@check_valid_token
def update_petty_cash(self, id, **rec):
    # import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
    user_id = request.uid
    petty_cash = request.env['petty.cash.app'].\
        search([('create_uid', '=', user_id),
                ('id', '=', id)
                ])

    image_file = rec.get("image", False)
    replace = image_file.replace(" ", "+")
    user_id = request.uid
    petty_cash.write({
        'reference': rec['reference'],
        'partner_id': rec['partner_id'],
        'state': petty_cash.state,
        'request_by': user_id,
        'date_requested': fields.Date.today(),
        'image': replace,

    })

    petty_cash_line = request.env['petty.cash.line'].sudo().search([('pety_cash_id', '=', petty_cash.id)])
    for product in eval(rec['products']):
        petty_cash_line.update({
            'pety_cash_id': petty_cash.id,
            'product_char': product['product_char'],
            'quantity': product['quantity'],
            'price_unit': product['price_unit'],
        })

    return valid_response(
        200, {
            "msg" : "Data Updated",
            # "data": petty_cash,
        }
    )
```

i have been looping in section bulk update data like this :

```
petty_cash_line = request.env['petty.cash.line'].sudo().search([('pety_cash_id', '=', petty_cash.id)])
    for product in eval(rec['products']):
        petty_cash_line.update({
            'pety_cash_id': petty_cash.id,
            'product_char': product['product_char'],
            'quantity': product['quantity'],
            'price_unit': product['price_unit'],
        })

    return valid_response(
        200, {
            "msg" : "Data Updated",
            # "data": petty_cash,
        }
    )
```

but data **product_char** in database just write 1 data, just value **M** changed data, whereas i get 2 value **product_char** from client side **A** and **M**,

this is result when i print **eval(rec['products'])**

[image]

```
i just want update data in 'petty.cash.line' model , data needs to update is :
1. product_char
2. quantity
3. price_unit
```

relation one2Many 'petty.cash.app' with 'petty.cash.line' is field:

```
 pety_cash_line_ids = fields.One2many('petty.cash.line', 'pety_cash_id', string='Pety Cash Lines', copy=True)
```

relation many2one 'petty.cash.line' with 'petty.cash.app' is field:

```
 pety_cash_id = fields.Many2one('petty.cash.app', string="Pety cash")
```

i have been change **update** method, to **write** method in odoo, but result is same, just write 1 data, whats wrong from my code ? please help

Thanks

Comment: Can you print out what data is in `eval(rec['products'])`?

Comment: i have updated my question with result data in eval(rec['products'])

Comment: get 2 values A and M, but data just write 1 data, Just M writed to db

Comment: It is because you are updating the product data both 'A' and 'M' sequentially into the same `petty_cash.id`, so the result is from 'M' since it is the last update.

Comment: how to updated data let both data 'A' and 'M' changed to database ?

Comment: What is the One2Many field that you want to update?

Comment: 'pety_cash_line_ids' is one2Many field want i update

Comment: is it in the model `petty.cash.line`?

Comment: 'pety_cash_line_ids' in the model header called 'petty.cash.app'

Comment: Please update the question with all of the data needed to solve the question. The model `petty.cash.app` and its fields that you want to update needs to be clarified in the question.

Comment: i have been updated my question, pls help, i stuck about an hour in this case 

@holydragon

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252369/discussion-between-holydragon-and-bian).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this code

```
petty_cash_line = request.env['petty.cash.line'].sudo().search([('pety_cash_id', '=', petty_cash.id)])
    for product in eval(rec['products']):
        petty_cash_line.update({
            'pety_cash_id': petty_cash.id,
            'product_char': product['product_char'],
            'quantity': product['quantity'],
            'price_unit': product['price_unit'],
        })
```

to

```
petty_cash_line = request.env['petty.cash.line'].sudo().search([('pety_cash_id', '=', petty_cash.id)])
products = eval(rec['products'])
for index, line in enumerate(petty_cash_line):
  line.update({
    'product_char': products[index]['product_char'],
    'quantity': products[index]['quantity'],
    'price_unit': products[index]['price_unit'],
})
```

That should get it to work because we loop update each line with its corresponding product from client.